# Mandrill file giving 500 error but still performing function

Tags: javascript, php, mandrill

I've got a mandrill PHP SDK being used to perform transactional emails from the user to the admin.

The problem I face is on submit of a form, the mandrill file gives an error 500 but it still performs the function and the admin is still getting the emails.

The mandrill PHP file:

```
<?php
require('./mandrill/Mandrill.php');
$html = 'Hey, <br>'.'You got mail from '.$_GET['Name'].' email: '.$_GET['Email'].' phone: '.$_GET['Phone'].'.<br>Their message is, '.$_GET['message'];
try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('KEY_GOES_HERE');
    $message = array(
        'html' => $html,
        'subject' => 'User Message',
        'from_email' => 'random@email.com',
        'from_name' => 'random_name',
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => 'to_random@email.com',
            )
        ),
        'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'none'),
        'important' => false,
        'track_opens' => null,
        'track_clicks' => null,
        'auto_text' => null,
        'auto_html' => null,
        'inline_css' => null,
        'url_strip_qs' => null,
        'preserve_recipients' => null,
        'view_content_link' => null,
        'bcc_address' => 'message.bcc_address@example.com',
        'tracking_domain' => null,
        'signing_domain' => null,
        'return_path_domain' => null,
        'merge' => true,
        'global_merge_vars' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'merge1',
                'content' => 'merge1 content'
            )
        ),
    );
    $async = false;


    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
    print_r($result);
    /*
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => recipient.email@example.com
                [status] => sent
                [reject_reason] => hard-bounce
                [_id] => abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123
            )

    )
    */
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
    // Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
    echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
    // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
    throw $e;
}
?>
```

The JavaScript to send the serialized form is as follows:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
    var e = $("#modal-contact-form").serialize();
    if (!n()) return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "./mandrill_mailer.php",
        data: e,
        success: function() {
            alert("Got it, thanks! We'll be in touch soon!");
            $("#modal-contact-form").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("")
        }
    });
    return false
});
```

This particular problem is being faced only on the GoDaddy hosting while it works perfectly on my localhost. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing 500 errors on occasion for invalid_key errors - for example, if you have an API key which is restricted. I wouldn't expect the email to still be sent though.

Have you checked the [API Logs](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/api)?